# InAppBrowserでカスタムヘッダを付加する方法

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui, angularjs

InAppBrowserで、
window.open('http://example.jp/', '_blank', 'location=yes');
などとする時、httpリクエストヘッダに
x-sample: abcd
などのカスタムヘッダを付加する方法は、何かありますでしょうか？
cordovaのバージョンは6.2です。
何卒、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

Monacaで標準プラグインとして提供されている[CordovaのInAppBrowserプラグイン](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser)は、現状リクエストヘッダを追加変更する方法を提供していないようです。

そのような機能を追加するプルリクエストは一年ほど前に提出されているものの、マージされていません。ご自身でこれを取り込んで使うことは可能かもしれませんが、その場合Monaca的にはカスタムCordovaプラグインということになるので、Gold以上のプランを使う必要があるかと思います。

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/pull/115